# White objects in a gray background when exported in the Egg format

Tags: export

I am creating an object to use in Panda3D, as below.

[image]

When I export it in the Egg format using YABEE 13.1,

[image]

The following is the export options:

[image]

the object is displayed white in a gray background like this:
[image]

I cannot find relevant previous posts about this problem.

Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain what steps are done in/relate to Blender?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear how it relates to Blender.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have edited the post with screenshots. Can you please share your opinion on how to address this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what that format can accept as exported data, however sky color set in Blender render engine will remain set only in Blender and won't be used as property in third-party format. It's likely that the same goes for material of the plane, Blender's material isn't accessible for other application. Export bump texture from Blender and construct shader in the end application, probably that's it

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you for your quick help!